# Как ускорить midpoint subdivision?

Tags: c++, алгоритм, opengl

Я смог реализовать алгоритм midpoint subdivision на OpenGL с помощью рекурсии, хотелось бы узнать, возможно ли как то сделать этот код еще быстрее и, если да, то как? Возможно использовать другую реализацию или что-то такое. Прикрепляю сам код:

```cpp
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
#include <windows.h>
#include <gl/GL.h>
#include <gl/glut.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

double
left_line = 2,
right_line = 8,
up_line = 9,
down_line = 2,
xmin = -1,
ymin = -1,
xmax = 10,
ymax = 10,
w = 500,
h = 500,
eps = 0.1;

int
up_area = 4,
down_area = 1,
right_area = 2,
left_area = 8;

using namespace std;

class Point
{
private:
    double _x, _y;

public:
    Point();
    Point(double x, double y);
    double getX();
    double getY();
    Point operator+(Point const& arg);
    Point operator-(Point const& arg);
    bool operator==(Point const& arg);
    static double scalarProduct(Point a, Point b);
    static double distance(Point a, Point b);
    void drawPoint();
};

Point::Point() { _x = 0; _y = 0; }

Point::Point(double x, double y) { _x = x; _y = y; }

double Point::getX()
{
    return _x;
}

double Point::getY()
{
    return _y;
}

Point Point::operator+(Point const& arg)
{
    return Point(_x + arg._x, _y + arg._y);
}

Point Point::operator-(Point const& arg)
{
    return Point(_x - arg._x, _y - arg._y);
}

bool Point::operator==(Point const& arg)
{
    return ((_x == arg._x) && (_y == arg._y));
}

double Point::scalarProduct(Point a, Point b)
{
    return (a._x * b._x + a._y * b._y);
}

double Point::distance(Point a, Point b)
{
    Point v = a - b;
    double d = sqrt(v._x * v._x + v._y * v._y);
    return d;
}

void Point::drawPoint()
{
    glColor3ub(0, 0, 0);
    glEnable(GL_POINT_SMOOTH);
    glPointSize(6);
    glBegin(GL_POINTS);
    glVertex2f(_x, _y);
    glEnd();
    glFlush();
}

int code(Point p)
{
    if ((p.getX() <= left_line) && (p.getY() <= down_line))
        return left_area + down_area;
    if ((p.getX() <= left_line) && (p.getY() >= up_line))
        return left_area + up_area;
    if ((p.getX() >= right_line) && (p.getY() <= down_line))
        return right_area + down_area;
    if ((p.getX() >= right_line) && (p.getY() >= up_line))
        return right_area + up_area;

    if (p.getX() < left_line)
        return left_area;
    if (p.getX() > right_line)
        return right_area;
    if (p.getY() < down_line)
        return down_area;
    if (p.getY() > up_line)
        return up_area;
    return 0;
}

int visible(Point p1, Point p2)
{
    int c1 = code(p1), c2 = code(p2);
    if (!(c1 + c2))
        return 1;
    if (c1 & c2)
        return -1;
    return 0;
}

void midpointSubdivision(Point p1, Point p2)
{
    if ((abs(Point::distance(p1, p2)) < eps) || (visible(p1, p2) == 1))
    {
        glColor3ub(255, 0, 0);
        glBegin(GL_LINES);
        glVertex2f(p1.getX(), p1.getY());
        glVertex2f(p2.getX(), p2.getY());
        glEnd();
        glFlush();
    }
    else if (visible(p1, p2) == 0)
    {
        Point mid((p1.getX() + p2.getX()) / 2, (p1.getY() + p2.getY()) / 2);
        midpointSubdivision(p1, mid);
        midpointSubdivision(mid, p2);
    }
}

Point p1 = Point(), p2;

void drawBoard()
{
    glEnable(GL_LINE_SMOOTH);
    glLineWidth(1);
    glColor3ub(250, 250, 250);
    glBegin(GL_LINES);
    for (int i = 2; i < 11; i++)
    {
        glVertex2f(xmin + i, ymin);
        glVertex2f(xmin + i, ymax);
        glVertex2f(xmin, ymin + i);
        glVertex2f(xmax, ymin + i);
    }
    glEnd();

    glLineWidth(2);
    glColor3ub(33, 96, 7);
    glBegin(GL_LINES);
    glVertex2f(0, ymin);
    glVertex2f(0, ymax);
    glVertex2f(xmin, 0);
    glVertex2f(xmax, 0);
    glEnd();

    glColor3ub(255, 0, 0);
    glBegin(GL_LINES);
    glVertex2f(left_line, ymin);
    glVertex2f(left_line, ymax);
    glVertex2f(right_line, ymin);
    glVertex2f(right_line, ymax);
    glVertex2f(xmin, up_line);
    glVertex2f(xmax, up_line);
    glVertex2f(xmin, down_line);
    glVertex2f(xmax, down_line);
    glEnd();
    p1.drawPoint();
    glFlush();
}

void clearWindow()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glFinish();
    glFlush();
    drawBoard();
}

void mouse(int button, int stats, int x, int y)
{
    if ((button == GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON) && (stats == GLUT_DOWN))
    {
        double x1 = x * (xmax - xmin) / w + xmin;
        double y1 = (h - y) * (ymax - ymin) / h + ymin;
        p2 = Point(x1, y1);
        int vis = visible(p1, p2);
        cout << "Visibility: " << vis << "\n";
        p2.drawPoint();

        if (vis == -1 || vis == 0)
        {
            glColor3ub(0, 0, 0);
        }
        else if (vis == 1)
        {
            glColor3ub(255, 0, 0);
        }

        glEnable(GL_LINE_SMOOTH);
        glBegin(GL_LINES);
        glVertex2f(p1.getX(), p1.getY());
        glVertex2f(p2.getX(), p2.getY());
        glEnd();
        glFlush();

        if (vis == 0)
        {
            midpointSubdivision(p1, p2);
        }
        p1 = p2;
    }

    if ((button == GLUT_RIGHT_BUTTON) && (stats == GLUT_DOWN))
    {
        clearWindow();
    }
}

void display(void)
{
    glEnable(GL_POINT_SMOOTH);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glColor3ub(0, 125, 1);
    glPointSize(15);
    drawBoard();
}

void init(void)
{
    glClearColor(0.9, 0.8, 0.0, 0.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax, -1.0, 1.0);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowSize(h, w);
    glutInitWindowPosition(800, 100);
    glutCreateWindow("hello world");
    init();
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutMouseFunc(mouse);
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0; /* ISO C requires main to return int. */
}
```